# How do I make this display inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists, inline

Can someone help me find the error when I tried to display the list in one line but it didn't do it.

```
#main-nav ul ul li { display: inline; }
```

But the text is not displaying line. Please take a look jsfiddle.net/EZJwM

Comment: I just did but it not displaying in one line.

Comment: You may want to consider using jsfiddle.net. I will not click that link no matter the caveat.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xZrx3/ - works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EZJwM/ notice how the gray bars at the bottom is not displaying in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the

```
display: inline
```

to

```
float:left
```

and got this http://jsfiddle.net/EZJwM/5/

The menu isn't centered but they display in one line.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I can center it? I tried `#main-nav{ margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}` but it is not working. I can't even get `© 2012 Bin.xxx, All Rights Reserved` to move down.

Answer (score 0):

[solution to your problem js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/nuKY6/)

i change `display:block` to `display:inline` to get it on one line but you have 
to work it out considering you style design i think for `main-nav` you should use css classes
to avoid intersection on what you exactly want otherwise you will get all so fuzzy

change 1

`#main-nav ul li{ display: inline; }`

change2

`#main-nav a:after {
        color: #aeaeae;
        content: attr(data-description);
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 400;
        display: inline;
        line-height: 0;
        margin: 3px 0 -3px;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        }`

change 3

`#main-nav ul ul a {
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #252525;
        border-top: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 8px 20px !important;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: none;
        }`